# Simplest way to set up python logging to stdout

Tags: python, logging

I have the following to set up a basic logger to print output in a cron job:

```
import logging
log=logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
log.info('hi')
```

Is this the most straightforward way to do this, or is there a better method?

Comment: Can you just write to a file?  A coworker once pointed this out to me, and for my situation that was enough.  Certainly simpler and avoids a dependency which can break easily.  EDIT: I initially misunderstood your question, thinking logging wasn't working for you.  As long as logging is working, your question is valid.  I do not know the answer offhand, unfortunately

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just need to print the messages to the stdout, then [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) is a handy shortcut for the configuration you listed. It will create a `StreamHandler`, attach the default `Formatter` to it and attach the handler to the root logger.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, stream=sys.stdout)
logging.getLogger().info('hi')
```

Check out the docs for more configuration possibilities; for example,

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='some.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

will configure writing to file `some.log` instead of stdout.

Note that `logging.basicConfig` won't do a thing if the logger is already configured (meaning that there are handlers attached to the root logger already). So this code:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.FileHandler(filename='some.log'))
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

will not configure logging to stdout anymore; you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: AFAICT, `basicConfig` by default outputs in STDERR, not STDOUT like the OP asked. you need to add `stream=sys.stdout` to the basicConfig

Comment: @Hilikus you're absolutely right, thanks for pointing that out!