# Showing INFO-level python logs on stdout without changing source code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

If a module whose source code I can't change says something like:

```py
# foo.py
import logging

logging.info('Hello world')
```

How can I see the logs while running

```
$ python foo.py
```

from my POSIX-compliant terminal?

[All](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14058475/2071807) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733863/2071807) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858741/2071807) [I](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688396/2071807) [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325975/2071807) [find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51669458/2071807) about this involve changing the source code.

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#a-simple-example) are pretty clear about logging WARN-level and above:

> The INFO message doesn’t appear because the default level is WARNING.

But I can't easily see how to change that default.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a script, or an importable module? If it's a module, just configure logging in your own code. If it's a script, it's the script's job to provide options to configure logging.

Comment: (And if it's a script with no options to configure logging, then it's likely that those logs were never meant to be shown to users at all - maybe they're a debug thing that got left in, or unnecessary code that got copy-pasted from a program that did have configurable logging.)

Comment: Also, do you really mean stdout? When logging to a standard stream, the usual choice is stderr.

Comment: Yeah, I should've said "the screen". I don't care between stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the script with an incantation that preconfigures `logging` for you (now 100% more Python3 compatible).

```
$ cat foo.py
import logging
logging.info('Hello world')

$ python3 -c 'import logging,sys,runpy;logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,stream=sys.stdout);runpy.run_path("foo.py")'
INFO:root:Hello world
~/Desktop
```

## Not memorable enough?

To make it more memorable, you can wrap things in a `please_log.py`. Some `sys.argv` finagling is required.

### please_log.py

```
import logging, sys, runpy
script = sys.argv.pop(1)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
runpy.run_path(script)
```

### foo.py

```
import logging
import sys

logging.info('Hello world: %s', sys.argv)
```

### output

```
$ python3 please_log.py foo.py
INFO:root:Hello world: ['foo.py']
```

Comment: I'll be sad if this turns out to be the best we can do here. Not exactly memorable!

Comment: Added a wrapper script option.

Comment: `execfile` doesn't exist in Python 3.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Oop, good point. Fixed :)

Comment: It does indeed seem like maybe `logging` doesn't have anything which can do better than this. I'd sort of expected there to be a `OVERRIDE_LOG_LEVEL=INFO python ...` envvar solution. Ah well. I live and learn.